# Как исправить ошибку "Could not parse call arguments or missing ')'", возникающую при сборке?

Tags: javascript, webpack, less

Необходимо подключить библиотеку FlipClock.js к проекту, использующему Webpack. Есть файл `style.less`, который импортирует `flipclock.css`:

`@import (less) "~flipclock/dist/flipclock.css"`

В `index.js` инициализирован таймер:

```
import "./style.less";
import "flipclock";

$(document).ready(function() {
    let clock = $('#flipclock').FlipClock()
});
```

При запуске команды `npm run dev` наблюдается следующая ошибка:

```
ERROR in ./src/style.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-3!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/style.less)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


            .flip-clock .flip-clock-group .flip-clock-list.flip .active .bottom:after {
              animation-delay: calc(inherit * .15);
                                          ^
    Could not parse call arguments or missing ')'
          in ...\node_modules\flipclock\dist\flipclock.css (line 85, column 40)
```

При удалении `(less)` из `@import (less) "~flipclock/dist/flipclock.css"` в консоли наблюдается ошибка `"FlipClock() is not a function"`.
Как исправить ошибку `Could not parse call arguments or missing ')'` и тем самым обеспечить подключение библиотеки к проекту?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибку в итоге исправил самостоятельно путем удаления `(less)` из `@import (less) "~flipclock/dist/flipclock.css"` и установки flipclock версии 0.8.0 вместо 0.10.0, установленной ранее.